# How to make sense of a definite integral equation which converges on one side but diverges on the other

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Say there is a real valued function $f(\mathbf{w})=1/h \nabla f \cdot \mathbf{w}$ where $h$ is a scalar (the degree of homogeneity of $f$, but don't worry about that), $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$ (a vector), and $\mathbf{w}$ is the vector of arguments of $f$. And say that $\nabla f$ is a random vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, while $\mathbf{w}$ are decision variables. And say there is the condition

$$\nabla f+2 \lambda \Sigma \cdot \mathbf{w} =\mathbf{0} \tag{1}$$

where $\mathbf{0}$ is a vector of zeros, and $\lambda$ is a scalar, so that an expression for $\lambda$ is obtained by dotting this through by $\mathbf{w}$

$$fh+2\lambda V =0 \tag{2}$$
$$-\frac{fh}{2V}=\lambda \tag{3}$$

(where $V=\mathbf{w} \cdot \Sigma \cdot \mathbf{w}$)

Also, premultiplying Eq. 1 by $\nabla f \cdot \Sigma^{-1}$ and substituting in Eq 3 gives:

$$\nabla f \cdot\Sigma^{-1}\cdot \nabla f - \frac{f^2h^2}{V}=0 \tag{4}$$

Rearranging and raising by $e$:

$$e^{-\nabla f \cdot\Sigma^{-1}\cdot \nabla f} = e^{-\frac{f^2h^2}{V}} \tag{5}$$

Now I get to my question. I'd like to derive a "nice" expression for $V$ resulting from the condition in Eq. 1 (perhaps, for example, in terms of the determinant of $\Sigma$) by integrating Eq. 5 and evaluating over a suitable domain. For example, a volume integration of the LHS of Eq. 5 over the entire domain $[-\infty, \infty]$ gives

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}...\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\nabla f \cdot\Sigma^{-1}\cdot \nabla f}\:d([\nabla f]_1) d([\nabla f]_2) ... d([\nabla f]_n) = \sqrt{\pi^n \det(\Sigma)} \tag{6}$$

($n$ being the length of $\nabla f$) but applying the same to the RHS of Eq. 5 does not (as far as I can tell) give a convergent result. On the other hand, integrating the RHS of Eq. 5 w.r.t. $f$ over the entire domain gives

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{f^2h^2}{V}} \:df = \sqrt{\pi \frac{V}{h} } \tag{7}$$

But applying same to the LHS of Eq. 5 does not (as far as I can tell) produce a convergent result.